# Как залить на github скачанный репозиторий *.zip

Tags: git, github

Разработчик передал код в zip формате как залить на свой репозитарий?

Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: `git init` -> `git add .` -> `git commit -m "init"` -> `git remote add origin URL` -> `git push -u origin master`

Comment: И да, код должен быть не в архиве, ибо какой тогда смысл от гитхаба, если вы неправильно используете этот отличный инструментарий.

Comment: скажите ему чтобы он сразу сам залил в репозиторий

Comment: Зачем вам заливать код на репозиторий, если вы не умеете им пользоваться.